# Grid layout for array data

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dynamic list whose data is coming from response.
I want to create a dynamic grid layout which will have 5 columns and no of rows will be as per the length of list.
If i have 10 data then columns should be 5 and rows should be 2.
If i have 10 data then columns should be 5 and rows should be 3.
How to achieve that using css ad javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = 9;
const grid = document.getElementById("main");
const elmBtn = document.getElementById("start");

  elmBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (data < 10 ) {
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = "auto auto auto";
  }
    for(let i = 0; i < data; i++){ 
        let column = document.createElement("div");
        column.className = 'column';
        grid.appendChild(column);
       }
    
  });
```

```css
#main{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>

<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;` to define the 5 columns. Then you have to loop over your data and create an element with `document.createElement()` and append it to the grid container with `document.createElement()`.

**Working example:** (*with single letters as dummy data for demonstration*)

```js
const grid = document.getElementById("grid-container");
const data = ['d', 'u', 'm', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't'];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  const cell = document.createElement("div");
  
  cell.textContent = item;
  
  grid.appendChild(cell);
});
```

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container"></div>
```

Comment: `repeat(5, auto);` (unless you really like typing).

Comment: Cool - Thank you!